# ¿La hora de salida es ...?

Tags: gramática, sintaxis

Ha surgido una duda en la oficina sobre la hora de salida, hay varias posibilidades:

- La hora de salida *es a las seis*. (Suena bien).
- La hora de salida *es las seis*. (Suena raro).
- La hora de salida *son las seis*. (Suena raro).
- La hora de salida *es la una*. (Suena bien).

El primero es claramente correcto pero tenemos dudas sobre si son válidas las otras tres formas, hemos mirado en [la RAE](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/?key=hora) pero no menciona este caso. (En cualquier caso me temo que la hora de salida es a las siete :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Al **responder**, para "**una**" se utiliza en **singular** pero para **las demás horas** se usa en **plural**. Ejemplo:

- Es la una (de la tarde/mañana).
- Son las dos (de la tarde/mañana).

Sin embargo la **pregunta** siempre va en **singular**. Ejemplo:

> **Pregunta**: ¿A qué hora es la salida?
>
> **Respuesta** 1: A las seis.
>
> **Respuesta** 2: La hora de salida es a las seis.
>
> **Respuesta** 3: La hora de salida es a la una.

Esto lo podemos confirmar según lo que dice la RAE al respecto de [hora](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/?key=hora):

> **hora2.** 1. Es la indicación del momento en que sucede o se hace una
>   cosa en relación con cada una de las veinticuatro partes en que se
>   divide el día. **La pregunta que corresponde a la indicación de la
>   hora se formula, en la lengua general culta, en singular: ¿Qué hora
>   es?** (en ella, la palabra hora tiene el sentido genérico de ‘momento
>   del día’). Su formulación en plural (¿Qué horas son?) es admisible,
>   aunque menos recomendable, y se da con cierta frecuencia en algunos
>   países de América, especialmente en el nivel popular: «—¿Qué horas
>   son, compa? —Van a dar las cinco» (Campos Carne [Méx. 1982]). Solo es
>   normal el plural en la frase hecha de intención reprobatoria ¿qué
>   horas son estas?: «¿Cómo que qué horas son estas de llamar? ¡Pero si
>   ha sido usted quien...!» (GaMay Operación [Esp. 1991]). **En la
>   respuesta, el verbo va en singular si se trata de la una (Es la una y
>   diez) y en plural en el resto de los casos (Son las diez y media; Son
>   las dos menos cuarto).**

Ahora respecto a por qué se utiliza la preposición "a" al preguntar y al responder, no encuentro una nota oficial en la RAE sin embargo de esa forma se utiliza aquí en México. Tambíen comunmente al preguntar se utiliza "cuándo".

- ¿Cuándo es la hora de salida?
- ¿Cuándo es la salida?

Contestando tu pregunta tomando en cuenta lo dicho, el único ejemplo válido de los ejemplos que proprocionaste es:

- La hora de salida es a las seis.

Answer (score 2):

Yo prefiero, igual que la mayoría de los hablantes, la primera opción.

Hay al menos dos problemas aquí

Primero: la eterna duda singular-plural para designar un instante horario. Es claro que *"las seis (horas)"* es plural, gramaticalmente hablando. Sin embargo generalmente se usa como sintagma singular. Y es lógico, ya que en la mayoría de los usos (como el que nos ocupa) designa un objeto singular: **un instante de tiempo**. En verdad, cuando decimos

> "La oficina cierra [a las quince horas]"

estamos diciendo, en forma abreviada

> "La oficina cierra [en el instante en que el reloj marca las quince horas]"
>
> "La oficina cierra [en el instante en que han transcurrido quince horas desde el comienzo del día]"

Así que el complemento es realmente singular. (De paso, nótese que a veces se usa la expresión  *"La oficina cierra [a la hora quince]"*, menos habitual y un poco dura, pero en este aspecto más clara.)

Y por eso, es correcto que la pregunta y respuesta vayan en singular:

> ¿Cuál es la hora de salida?
>
> La hora de salida es las seis de la tarde.

(El único caso en que se acepta el plural es para : ¿Qué hora/s es/son? Son las seis)

Es cierto, de todas maneras, que suena un poco raro. Lo cual nos lleva a la segunda duda,
sobre la preposición:

> "La hora de salida es **a** las seis de la tarde"

De nuevo, ateniéndonos a la solo gramática, esto no es muy correcto, no hay que agregar la preposición *a* en este tipo de construcción. Se está confundiendo con la construcción *"Salimos a las seis de la tarde"*. Pero el hablante tiende a hacerlo, probablemente para suavizar esa disonancia (plural aparente cuando se espera un complemento singular). Y mí, diga lo que dijere la RAE, me parece bien.

Otro ejemplo relacionado (no totalmente equivalente). Si yo digo "El destino de esta donación es la sociedad de fomento", no hay nada que objetar. Pero si el complemento es plural (aparente) como "los discapacitados", dudamos:

1. "El destino de esta donación es los discapacitados"
2. "El destino de esta donación son los discapacitados"
3. "El destino de esta donación es para los discapacitados"

Ninguna satisface. 1: choca el complemento plural con el verbo. 2: choca el verbo plural con el sujeto singular. 3: es gramaticalmente incorrecta, confunde complementos. Esta última opción es análoga a nuestra primera opción (agregar el 'a'), pero en este caso suena bastante peor; preferiríamos reformular la frase como
"El destino de esta donación es el conjunto de los discapacitados" (metemos la pluralidad en un singular). O "Esta donación está destinada a los discapacitados".

Answer (score 1):

Para entender porque suenan raro las opciones que especificas es necesario descomponer la oración de la siguiente forma:

> La hora de salida -> es el sujeto.
>
> es -> es el verbo.
>
> a las seis -> es un complemento del verbo.

Ya que estamos hablando de "la hora de salida" que es singular, el verbo debe ser también en singular y por eso se usa "es" en lugar de "son".

Ahora bien, también es importante usar la preposición "a" antes de decir la hora. Aquí no soy capaz de dar la explicación gramatical, simplemente te puedo decir que esa es la forma correcta de construir esta frase. Quizás alguien más podría complementar con esa explicación.